# How to ignore mail header in mu4e for visual-fill-column-mode

Tags: hooks, mu4e, email, wrapping

When setting a `mu4e-view-mode-hook` to fill columns for easy reading and without having to hard wrap the lines with fill-mode, then it also wraps the mail header, what makes it rather unreadable. Is there a way to ignore the header in the hook?

```
    (add-hook 'mu4e-view-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            ;; use soft wrap on window boundary
            (visual-line-mode t)
            ;; and specific column
            (visual-fill-column-mode)
            (set-fill-column 60)
             ))
```

Emacs 28.0.50, Mu4e 1.62